# dax calculation for costume measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

i have a 2 tables that looks like this

Key |Num Of Treatments| Cost |

```
1        2           1000 
1        2           1500
1        2           2000
2        3            700  
3        3            800
4        4            900
```

key | limit |

```
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
```

the calculation that i want to do on dax is : (Num Of Treatments-Limit)*cost/Num Of Treatments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `key` column is unique for the second table (`Table2` in dax).

```
Calculation =
VAR _limit =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Table2[limit], Table2[key], [key] )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( ( [Num Of Treatments] - _limit ) * [cost], [Num Of Treatments] )
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily be achieved after creating one to many relationship between two tables with column **Key**.

Dax formula :

```
New Measure = ((SUM(Asset[No Of Treatments])-SUM(Tickets[Limit]))*SUM(Asset[Cost]))/SUM(Asset[No Of Treatments])
```

[image]

[image]